# Removing the numbers after a decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame in which I am replacing the null values with the average. I have the code

```py
data['GarageYrBlt'].fillna(data['GarageYrBlt'].average(), inplace = True)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the decimals, or to round the answer to the nearest whole number.

Comment: Have you looked at the `round` function?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add round(0)

```
data['GarageYrBlt'].fillna(data['GarageYrBlt'].average().round(0), inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) will truncate floats (towards zero) and [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) will round them (towards even).